# How to debug a page which is in the middle of an order flow using netbeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I have a PHP based online order flow system. It is a three page process and we were having issues on the second page of the order process. After a lot of echoing and dieing I was able to figure out and fix it. So I decided to install netbeans and use its awesome debugging functionalities. It works fine, if I am debugging the first page which is a direct URL, but in the debug session when I click on the next button and move to the second page, all debug info gets lost!

How can I debug a php page that is not directly accessible from the browser but is part of a sequence of button clicks?